# How to save One to Many Relationship to database

Tags: laravel-5, orm, one-to-many

Below is my LevelOneModel. I can't seem to figure out what I have not included. Please I need assistance.

What I want to achieve is to have all the users id in the levelone table

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class LevelOneModel extends Model
{
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

}
```

Below is my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 
    'last_name', 
    'email',
    'phone',
    'bank_name',
    'acct_name',
    'acct_number',
    'profile_pix',
    'sme',
    'other_sme',
    'password',
];

public function levelone()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\LevelOneModel');
}

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

And below is my level one migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLevelOneTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('level_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('upline_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('level_one');
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No error. Before now I was not following the naming convention. My model name was not in sync with my table name, but have corrected that now. I am new to Laravel. Don't really know how to connect the user table to the levelone table as a user registers.

Comment: Don't know how to populate the levelone table to get the column filled as users register.

Answer (score 0):

I notice some things in your code....

Looking at your classes, I understand the relationship is like this

- a user belongs to one LevelOne only.
- a LevelOne can have multiple users

If that is correct, the relationship is incorrectly build in the migration. Because you are adding a user_id to the level_one table.

It should be the other way around: the user tabel must contain a level_one_id.

And you should add it in the User migration, something like:

```
$table->int('level_one_id');
$table->foreign('level_one_id')->references('id')->on('level_one');
```

Now you have (in the database) a connection between User and LevelOne.

Now, if you query a user in your code, you should be able to get the LevelOne stuff as well. Make sure to really read the official Laravel documentation on relationships! It will really help you with examples.